# How to resolve path inside grunt plugin task to its own resources?

Tags: gruntjs

I have a sample grunt plugin

```
/tasks
   sample.js
   config.file
Gruntfile.js
package.json
```

I want to get the path to the config.file inside the sample.js. At first, I did it like this

```
path.resolve('tasks/config.file')
```

It was OK until the plugin had been installed. Path to the config.file changed to '~/some_project/node_modules/sample_plugin/tasks/config.file' but `path.resolve` returned '~/some_project/tasks/config.file'.

How can I get proper path to the config.file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that I asked the question in the wrong direction. My question belonged to the nodejs not to the gruntjs. Answer is a [__dirname](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) directive. You can get full path to the config.file like this: `__dirname + path.sep + 'config.file'`